# Why does my FFmpeg video made from several .jpeg files have low quality?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working on a project, and I had to put a bunch of images together into a single video animation. I decided to try out and learn FFmpeg so I could avoid manually putting the images together. The image quality is around something like [this.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itZow8P18Ctz5SSGV1hFMv_xukOXIrbC/view?usp=sharing) So I first tried this:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i File_%03d.jpeg outputName.mp4
```

For a few seconds, it looked okay. But as time went on, weird spots and lines of color started appearing, and some of the frames even rotated and resized, though they were high enough quality.

[Here's a screenshot of a weird frame filled with color that wasn't there before.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itZow8P18Ctz5SSGV1hFMv_xukOXIrbC/view?usp=sharing)
[And here's a screenshot of a rotated and resized frame that doesn't have the weird colors.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1baL-5-0-2bvecUmu-IKKWTcltEwCDR1c/view?usp=sharing)

I also saw a [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561715/using-ffmpeg-to-encode-a-high-quality-video) that I thought would help, so I tried putting `-vb 20M` in the command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i File_%03d.jpeg -vb 20M outputName.mp4
```

I couldn't see much of a difference when doing this, though.

I have made sure all the photos are the same dimensions, and rotated the same way. I am using a Mac.

How can I make sure that the frames don't rotate, and that the images are like the original in terms of quality?

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -framerate 1 -reinit_filter 0 -i File_%03d.jpeg -f null - -report` and share the report file.

Comment: @Gyan Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hgi0RftQPP8y855iPlPIlEPO9afsxCvw/view?usp=sharing):

Comment: 12 of the images are of a different size, possibly rotated : 3k x 4k. Nos. 10,49-58 and 77.